# Удаление слов в Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот такой код. Он удаляет указанное слово в Edit из текстового файла.

**Теперь вопрос:** Как сделать что бы одновременно можно было удалять несколько слов. То есть указываю в **edit1 - слово** и **edit2 - слово** и программа одновременно удаляет два слова. Заранее благодарна...

```
var f1,f2:TextFile; s:string; p:Word;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\out.txt');
{$i-}
Reset(f1); Rewrite(f2);
    while not Eof(f1) do begin
        Readln(f1,s);
        repeat
        p:=Pos(edit1.Text,s);
        if p<>0 then Delete(s,p,p+length(edit1.Text)-1);
        until p=0;
      Writeln(f2,s);
    end;
CloseFile(f1);
CloseFile(f2);
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  ...
  toDelete: TStringList;
  iDelete: integer;

begin    
  toDelete := TStringList.Create;
  toDelete.Add(edit1.Text);
  toDelete.Add(edit2.Text);

  ...

    while not Eof(f1) do begin
      Readln(f1, s);
      for iDelete := 0 to toDelete.Count - 1 do begin 
        repeat
          p := Pos(toDelete[iDelete], s);
          if p <> 0 then 
            Delete(s, p, p + Length(toDelete[iDelete]) - 1);
        until p = 0;
      end;
      Writeln(f2, s);
    end;

  ...

  toDelete.Free;
```